# CSS Custom checkbox with label on wrong side

Tags: css, checkbox

This method of customizing a checkbox is new to me. I can customize, and put a label on it. Now I simply want to move the label to the LEFT of the checkbox. HTML and CSS is below the jsFiddle link. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/q3d8p321/1/

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing" />
<label for="thing">label</label>
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    background: #999;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: #0080FF;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Comment: what have you tried, or are you waiting for someone to just fix it? Maybe "Now I simply want to move the label to the LEFT of the checkbox" should be "Now I simply want someone else to move the label to the LEFT of the checkbox"

Comment: Please ignore the tactless comment above. The site is not meant for people that know the answers to show off, its here for people of different levels to help one another. Gave you an up-vote to set you to zero again.

Comment: Weirdly, the 'id' attribute on the input is crucial for this to work. Normally, just the 'for' attribute on the label + the 'name' attribute on the input is enough to link them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 16px 0 0;
    min-height: 16px;
    background: no-repeat right center / 16px 16px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #999, #999);
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0080FF, #0080FF);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q3d8p321/4/)

Instead of setting a `height` and `width`, I set a `min-height` and a `padding-right`.

Then I fill that padding:

- `background-image` sets the color.
- `background-size: 16px 16px` sets the size.
- `background-position: right center` places the background in the padding.
- `background-repeat: no-repeat` prevents the background to repeat outside the padding.

It must be `background-image` instead of `background-color` in order to make `background-size` work. Therefore I used `linear-gradient`, alternative ways could be svg or a data URI containing a 1x1 px image.

When the checkbox is checked, I change the `background-image`.

Comment: @dt1000 Consider accepting my [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25677483/1529630) instead. It's more intuitive, flexible (e.g. in case you want to add borders to the customized checkbox), clearer (without those repeating `linear-gradient`s), and probably faster to render (because lacks `linear-gradient`s).

Answer (score 0):

Move the label declaration to the 'left' of the checkbox in html, then change the css selectors around as well to label + input[checkbox]...

**HTML**

```
<label for="thing">label</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='thing' value='valuable' id="thing" />
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}
label + input[type=checkbox] {
    background: #999;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
label + input[type=checkbox]:checked  {
    background: #0080FF;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    display: none;
}
input[type=checkbox] + label:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    background-color: #999;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    background-color: #0080FF;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q3d8p321/5/)

Basically, instead of converting the `label` into the customized checkbox, I do that with a pseudo-element.